# How to load the caching layer with data when asp.net core web api is created?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1, distributed-caching

I have created a web api that handles the creation of jwt token based on the encrypted user details that it receives in a post request.

In addition to this STS api should also handle the population of the caching layer (Redis or Hazelcast) with all the user data present in the database. Presently I have registered the caching service using dependency injection.This will happen only once when the api is first initialized.

```C#
services.AddSingleton<ICacheService, RedisCacheService>();
```

And in the TokenController added the service as a parameter to initialize the CachingService class and thereby initialize the caching layer.So that when the cacheService object is fist initialized it fetches all the user rows from the database and stores it as a key value pair inside Redis/Hazelcast database.

```C#
public TokenController(
        ICryptographyService cryptographyService,
        crudDBContext crudDBContext,
        IConfiguration configuration,
        ICacheService cacheService)
    {
        _cryptographyService = cryptographyService;
        _context = crudDBContext;
        _config = configuration;
        _cacheService = cacheService;
    }
```

But the Token Controller constructor is initialized only when an endpoint is called, so i had to create a separate default [HttpGet] endpoint to ensure that the constructor is called when the STS api is first initialized so as to ensure that the cacheService object gets created and the data gets loaded to the cache.

```C#
 public  ActionResult<string> Get()
    {
        return "STS";
    }
```

Please let me know if there is a proper way of doing this without calling an endpoint, like be able to use dependency injection but at the same time call some code without the endpoint being called.I need to use dependency injection because i should be able to switch between Redis and Hazelcast by just changing the classname in the startup.cs file.

Answer (score 0):

With respect to Hazelcast and dependency injection: First you would need to use the [sources](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-csharp-client/tree/master/src/Hazelcast.Net.DependencyInjection) and not the Hazelcast NuGet version. Next the configuration depends on if you are in a [Container Environment](http://hazelcast.github.io/hazelcast-csharp-client/4.1.0/doc/configuration.html#container-environment) or a [Hosted Environment](http://hazelcast.github.io/hazelcast-csharp-client/4.1.0/doc/configuration.html#hosted-environment). In both cases configuration keys will be gathered from the same sources and in the same order, and options will be registered in the service container, and available via dependency injection

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you meant by "use the sources". I was initially calling a controller action when the API gets launched so that the call to load cache is called, what i was looking for was a way to do it while app starts up. I now call it in the Configure method, any code added in the configure method is only called once. Is there a way to make Hazelcast listen to the database directly?